# Execute a function into another function

Tags: jquery, function, qtip2

I would like to initiate a function by including it in another. In this case, I would like to initiate the function `print_help_A_0()` during the `Check_Index()` function is being executed :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#Demeler', Check_Index);
    $(document).on('click', '#Hasard', Check_Index);

    function Check_Index() {

        var choixA = $('#ChoixA').val().toUpperCase();
        var choixA_l = choixA.length;
        var choixB = $('#ChoixB').val().toUpperCase();
        var choixB_l = choixB.length;

        if(choixA_l == 0 & choixB_l == 0){$('#ChoixA').focus();}
        [...]
        else if(choixA !=  choixB ){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id == "Demeler"){
                //run my function print_help_A_0()
            }else if(id ="Hasard"){[...]}
        }
    };

    function print_help_A_0() {         
        var bulle_help_A_0 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_help_A_0')); ?>;
        var bulle_misska = $('#misska').qtip({
                content: {text: bulle_help_A_0+'<input type="button" value="go !" id="print_help_A_1"/>'},
                style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
                position: {my: 'right center',at: 'center left'},
        show: 'none',hide:'none'
    });
    var api_bulle_misska = bulle_misska.qtip('api');
    api_bulle_misska.show();
    };       
});
```

when I write `[...]`, it's just to simplified my code.

Any idea ? Because, `$(document).print_help_A_0();` doesn't work...

Comment: Just `print_help_A_0();`

Comment: Yes it's on, it's easier and ^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You $(document).function doesn't work because you declare your functions inside $(function(){}), declare at document level, put only initialization code inside $(function(){}), Ex:

```
function Check_Index() {

    var choixA = $('#ChoixA').val().toUpperCase();
    var choixA_l = choixA.length;
    var choixB = $('#ChoixB').val().toUpperCase();
    var choixB_l = choixB.length;

    if(choixA_l == 0 & choixB_l == 0){$('#ChoixA').focus();}
    [...]
    else if(choixA !=  choixB ){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id == "Demeler"){
            print_help_A_0()
        }else if(id ="Hasard"){[...]}
    }
};

function print_help_A_0() {         
    var bulle_help_A_0 = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('bulle_help_A_0')); ?>;
    var bulle_misska = $('#misska').qtip({
            content: {text: bulle_help_A_0+'<input type="button" value="go !" id="print_help_A_1"/>'},
            style: {classes: 'qtip-light'},
            position: {my: 'right center',at: 'center left'},
            show: 'none',hide:'none'
    });

    var api_bulle_misska = bulle_misska.qtip('api');
    api_bulle_misska.show(); 
};

$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#Demeler', Check_Index);
    $(document).on('click', '#Hasard', Check_Index);      
});
```